# How to find path of a file or directory in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I want to develop an application on windows phone 8.this app search all music on internal storage and SD card for this work i need to  path of directory and file.

```
   StorageFolder sf=KnownFolders.CameraRoll;
   string p=sf.Path;
   string[] a=Directory.GetDirectories(p);
```

p is null after runing.

Comment: This page on MSDN may be useful - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681698(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the Windows Phone SDK, but you could check something like this to get started:

```
  string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic);
```

Comment: `Environment.GetFolderPath` should be. Pick a `SpecialFolder` that does exist and navigate to your music from there.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var storageAssets = await ExternalStorage.GetExternalStorageDevicesAsync();
 ExternalStorageDevice item = storageAssets.FirstOrDefault();
 ExternalStorageFolder folder = item.RootFolder;
 var _folderList = await folder.GetFoldersAsync();
 foreach (var _folder in _folderList)
 {
 Debug.WriteLine(_folder.Name);
 }
```

Comment: What are the External Storage Devices? SD cards or remote media servers?